# Access image alt attribute in field template

Tags: 8, theming

I have copied the field.html.twig Template to field--node--field-image--article.html.twig, to specialize the template for my needs.
In this case the template would be called for content type article and field type image. (This content type uses the *Responsive Image* module.)

As default, with the image field, you must define an alt-value for the image.
But the alt-value is processed in the template image.html.twig.

Is it possible, to access the alt-value in the field--node--field-image--article.html.twig (the copy of field.html.twig), which calls the image.html.twig via the responsive-image templates.

I want to display the alt text in a div near the image.

I also have tried to access it in `hook_preprocess_field()`, but all I have for now is the following code.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_image') {
    foreach ($variables['element']['#items'] as $item_key => $item) {
      // code to write
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With twig a preprocess function won't be necessary to get at this data (yay). Unfortunately we still have some weird "drupalisms" to deal with due to the render API. At any rate, here's how you get to it:

```
{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}
```

And here's the issue on d.o accounting for the drupalism (linked directly to comment with the above solution and explanation): https://www.drupal.org/node/2160611#comment-9358305